# Recurrence relations with unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $$D_n = \frac{1}{b-a}((a^nb-ab^n)(a+b)+(b^n-a^n)(a^2+ab+b^2))$$

where $a≠b$.

Find $D_n$ if $a=b$ in terms of $a$ and $n$.

I had to solve a recurrence relation to end up with the above answer and the hint for this part is to let $b$ in my answer tend to $a$.

However, doesn't the function become undefined in such a case?

Any fast responses will be greatly appreciated, as I have to submit this in 30 minutes ):

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If you multiply out the numerator and simplify, you get
$$
(a^nb-ab^n)(a+b)+(b^n-a^n)(a^2+ab+b^2)
  = b^{n+2} - a^{n+2}
$$
Can you factor out $(a-b)$ or $(b-a)$ from that?

**UPDATE**

You have
$$
\begin{split}
(a^nb-ab^n)&(a+b)+(b^n-a^n)(a^2+ab+b^2) \\
 &= \left[a^{n+1}b + a^nb^2 -a^2b^n - ab^{n+1}\right]\\
 &+ \left[a^2b^n - a^{n+2} + ab^{n+1} - a^{n+1}b + b^{n+2} - a^nb^2 \right] \\
 &= b^{n+2}-a^{n+2}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Can I use the factorisation for $b^n-a^n$ and let $n=n+2$?

Comment: @EthanLeong exactly

Comment: @EthanMark you just multiply it out and cancel the like terms, see the update

Comment: I see! Omg how could I have missed something so trivial. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Letting $b$ tend to $a$ does not make it undefined.  You will get an indeterminate of the form $\frac 00$, but are taking the limit where $b \neq a$ but tends there.  You need either to divide the factor $b-a$ out of the numerator analytically, which is easy for the second term but not for the first, or write $b=a+\epsilon$, let $\epsilon \to 0$ and use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: I am only taking basic Linear Algebra and have not learnt that rule ): I know how to handle the 2nd term, but could you elaborate on how I could simplify the first?

Comment: @Ethan: Are you taking basic linear algebra in the sense of algebraic manipulations with linear terms, or as in talking about transformations of vector spaces, matrices and the like?

Comment: @YiFan the latter! :)

Answer (score 1):

The second term vanish, the first equals $$\dfrac{1}{b-a}(ab)(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})(a+b)=-ab(a+b)(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a^ib^{n-2-i})$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does the second term vanish?

Comment: for $a \to b$ or $b\to a$

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simple if you let $b=a(1+\epsilon)$. This would make
$$D_n=a^{n+1}\frac{ \left((1+\epsilon )^{n+2}-1\right)}{\epsilon }$$Using the binomial expansion or equivalents
$$(1+\epsilon )^{n+2}=1+(n+2)\epsilon+\cdots$$ Replacing
$$D_n=(n+2)a^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thank you for your input, but what’s the rational for letting $b=a(1+e)$? How am I supposed to have deduced that?

Comment: @EthanLeong. First of all, the expression is homogeneous; then, making $b=ka$ make it simpler. Then, since $b\to a$, $k=1+\epsilon$ seems to be a simple way to say it. Is i clearer ?

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I can see that the equation is homogenous, after much observation, but how does that allow me to let =? I’m sorry if this is something trivial; Mathematics has always been my forte, until I was made to take Linear Algebra in college ):

Comment: @EthanMark this is exactly what happens with $b=ka$ when $k=1+\epsilon$ for convenience...

Comment: @gt6989b Oh no, as in I understand that since we have proposed to let $b=ka$, then letting $k=1+e$ simplifies things a lot, but my question is how do we even arrive at the conclusion to let $b=ka$, just by observing that the equation is homogenous? Is it by intuition?

Comment: @EthanMark basically, it is clear you will have to take some sort of limit as $b \to a$. There are two simple approaches to do this. One is to set $b = a + \epsilon$ or to set $b = a(1 + \epsilon)$, and in either case let $\epsilon \to 0$. In the first case, you deal with absolute error, in the second one -- with relative error. Some problems are better off with one of these ways, some with the other. Yours deals with powers, so relative error sounds like an easier scenario to deal with...

Comment: @gt6968b I see. I am not well-versed with the concept of limits. I have not taken calculus in College yet, so I am relying on A Level knowledge, but I think I roughly understand what you are trying to say. My last question then is, does this only work for homogenous equations? Otherwise, why is the fact that this equation is homogenous relevant?